# Lookup, browse and search (GET) requests

Tags: database

I am sure it is a simple question but I don't manage to get a good answer on google.

When talking about APIs and datasets, what are the differences between lookup, browse and search (GET?) requests?

I write the "GET" in parenthesis because I am not sure whether these three requests are only "GET" requests or they may belong also to some other kind of requests.

As you see I am pretty new to this field.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What does this have to do with sql?

Comment: probably nothing, sorry for that. I'll remove that tag

Answer (score 0):

`GET` is an HTTP method used to request data.

Lookup, browse, search aren't actual methods that I know of, but you're probably seeing them as descriptive words used to show what a `GET` request can do.